# Configure SSL two different containers. One on 443. One on a non-443. Both Nginx

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, strapi

I'm trying to configure SSL for two containerized applications on one host.

Application 1: Standard SSL config on port 443. Nginx. --publish 443:443. Works great.

Application 2. SSL config on port 8000. Nginx. --publish 8000:1337 (Strapi CMS).

`docker run` for app1:

```
docker run -d --name app1 \
    --publish 80:80 \
    --publish 443:443 \
    --volume /home/app1/packages/app1/nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d \
    --volume /home/app1/packages/app1/nginx/certs/dev:/etc/nginx/certs \
    azureacr.azurecr.io/website:latest-dev
```

`docker run` for app2:

```
docker run -d --name app2 \
    --publish 8000:1337 \
    --volume vol1:/app2/data \
    --volume vol2:/app2/public/uploads \
    azureacr.azurecr.io/websitecms:latest-dev
```

`nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/private.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

}

server {
    listen 8000 ssl;
    server_name website.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/private.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

}
```

`curl -v` output

```
* Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == 'http://proxy.com:8080'
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to proxy.com (X.X.X.X) port 8080 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to website.com:8000
> CONNECT website.com:8000 HTTP/1.1
> Host: website.com:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to website.com:8000 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to website.com:8000
```

Any thoughts on how to get get both Applications 1 and 2 working on the same host?

Comment: Can you mention the full docker command you use to run these two containers ?

Comment: @rootkonda added

Comment: Very interesting question about using 2 containers web server with SSL...